# Does svn hotcopy overwrite existing files?

Tags: svn, backup

I have used SVN hotcopy to make a backup of the repository every weekday. When I looked at the Windows Scheduled Task logs I see that the job has run successfully. When I do a svnadmin verify I don't seem to only have a subset of the revisions. Do I need to delete the files first or is there an overwrite existing flag. svnadmin help hotcopy revealed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the verify command and I cannot find some of the revisions. When I delete it and run the svn hotcopy command again then they verify output now includes the missing revisions. I guess that means that it does not overwrite them. I cannot seem to find a flag that will let me overwrite the files. If no one else offers up an answer I will have to pick this one as being the right answer.